# How do you update a column's value in a dataframe based off of another row?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following data-frame:

```
id action  timestamp           time_difference opened
1  sent    2017-06-29 18:38:03 _NaN_           _NaN_
1  clicked 2017-06-29 18:40:03 _NaN_           _NaN_
2  sent    2017-06-29 18:38:03 _NaN_           _NaN_
```

I would like the end result to be one row, with the 2nd one combined into the previous. The time difference label would be calculated, and the opened would be set to one if a matching id with the "clicked" status is found.

```
id action  timestamp           time_difference opened
1  sent    2017-06-29 18:38:03 00:02:00        1
2  sent    2017-06-29 18:38:03 _NaN_           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two datasets- one for sent and one for clicked and merge them on id and then do the calculations

```
import pandas as pd
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df_sent = df[df['action']=='sent'][['id', 'timestamp']]
df_clicked = df[df['action']=='clicked'][['id', 'timestamp']]
df_clicked.columns = ['id', 'ts_clicked']

dfm = df_sent.merge(df_clicked, on='id', how='left')
dfm['time_difference'] = dfm['ts_clicked'] - dfm['timestamp']
dfm['opened'] = pd.notnull(dfm['ts_clicked'])*1
dfm = dfm[['id', 'timestamp', 'time_difference', 'opened']]
```